# Modifying android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, keypad, android-keypad

i would like to add my own key "X" by editing the previous one like "Done", or else is it possible to add a new key to the keyboard framework in Android. I want my button like this. i tried using Ime.option Label but cant works me. i get this image from iPhone keyboard but i would like to modify android's "Phone" type Keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own input method editor. There is a sample editor with your SDK.

However, what you cannot do is write an input method editor and force users to use it. Users have to agree to install your input method editor and select to use it.